# Can I have a function with the same name in PHP

Tags: php

Can I have a function with the same name do multiple things.

e.g

```
    function name () {
    echo "this";
    }

    function name () {
    echo "that";
    }

name();
```

so the same function doing multiple tasks.

Comment: it is impossible unless you put them into separate namespaces

Comment: Kind of hard to explain, this is why i made a simplified version of my question @MadDog

Comment: then how do you call a specific one?

Comment: @Kevin, try to explain. Otherwise, the answer is obvious.

Comment: I think you can do with `class` and create different method in same class.

Comment: and when calling `name()`, how would PHP know *which one* to execute?

Comment: wouldn't it just execute all of them at once? @FranzGleichmann

Comment: @Kevin as you would know if you simply *tried* it: no. also: "all at once" - you mean in parallel? that would require very complicated thread-handling for a feature never used. one after another? in which order? and which result would be returned?

Comment: `so the same function doing multiple tasks.` ... Yes by not splitting up what the function has to do in 2 tasks, but instead see it as 1 task?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you are right.But he can create a `class` with different  method and call them when he need.If he wants call them at once then he can create `construct` of a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible, and will yield

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare name() (previously declared in ...) in
>   php shell code on line ...